# error: unknown type name 'interface_tile'

Tags: c, gcc

**Header (render.h):**

```
struct interface_tile
{
    char tile[30][120];
};

int render_map_entities(int player_x, int player_y, interface_tile map);
```

**C file (render.c):**

```
int render_map_entities(int player_x, int player_y, interface_tile map)
{
    //Code
}
```

**Main C file:**

```
#include"render.h"
```

**GCC Compile:**

```
render.h:6:53: error: unknown type name 'interface_tile'
    6 | int render_map_entities(int player_x, int player_y, interface_tile map);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

typedef in the header doesn't solve the problem, but maybe I just used it incorrectly.

thank you in advance

Comment: You didn't show the typedef you tried. A *correct* typedef would definitely solve the issue. Alternatively, you could correct your function prototype.

Comment: In C, `struct interface_tile { ... }` declares a type named `struct interface_tile`.  Not one named `interface_tile`.  (C++ differs in this regard.)

Comment: Opinions differ in this area, but I am in the camp that recommends avoiding `typedef` for structure types.  To use a structure type declared elsewhere without relying on a typedef, you (1) give the structure a tag (which you have done), and (2) refer to the type via the form `struct the_tag`.

Comment: Well, I do not know how to write typedef and structures correctly since I am just learning C and I would be very grateful if you could tell me.

Comment: @John Bollinger " refer to the type via the form `struct the_tag` " how to refer to the type?

Comment: Are you asking what I mean by "refer"?  I just mean that wherever you want to declare an object of your structure type or to derive another type related to it (say a pointer to a structure or an array of structures) you use the keyword `struct` before the tag name.  In this particular case, that would be `struct interface_tile`, as I already observed in a previous comment.  Aso, this and more is well covered in the dupe targets.  Do read some of the higher-scoring answers to those.